# what is the possible reason for a runtime error in my implementation of BST?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have written a simple implementation BST in C++ but due to some reason I am getting error process returned 255 ( 0xFF ). I have tried adding a lot of print lines but the program crashes as soon as i run it. can someone please point out what can be the possible cause of such an error.

thank you

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
public:
    node( )
    {
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
    friend class bsTree;
};

class bsTree
{
    node* _root; //pointer to root node
    int n;

public:

    bsTree()
    {
        _root = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }

    int size(){ return n; }

    node* root(){ return _root; }

    bool empty()
    {
        if( n == 0 ) return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool isExternal( node* loc )
    {
        if( loc->left == NULL && loc->right == NULL )
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    void addRoot( int info )
    {
        node* newnode = new node();
        newnode->data = info;
        _root = newnode;
    }

    void insert( node*, int );
    //void erase( int );
    node* search( node*, int );
};

node* bsTree :: search( node* loc ,int value)
{
    if( isExternal( loc ) )
        return loc;
    if( loc->data <= value )
        return search( loc->left, value );
    else
        return search( loc->right, value );
    return loc;
}

void bsTree :: insert( node* loc, int info )
{
    node* newnode = new node();
    newnode->data = info;
    node* parent = search( loc, info );
    if( isExternal( parent ) )
    {
        if( parent->data <= info )
            parent->left = newnode;
        else
            parent->right = newnode;
    }
    else
        return insert( parent->left, info );
}

int main()
{
    bsTree mybst;
    mybst.addRoot( 50 );
    mybst.insert( mybst.root(), 30 );
    mybst.insert( mybst.root(), 60 );
    mybst.insert( mybst.root(), 40 );
    mybst.insert( mybst.root(), 20 );
    mybst.insert( mybst.root(), 10 );
    mybst.insert( mybst.root(), 70 );
    int enter;
    cin >> enter;
    node* w = (mybst.search( mybst.root(),enter));
    cout << w;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and the errors are...?

Comment: process returned 255 ( 0xFF )

Comment: In your search method, if your parent has only one child, you will pass nullptr to search and then try to access left or right which will cause an error.

Comment: but the program doesn't even run

Comment: The first bug might be that search does not handle "not-found" correctly.  i.e. "isExternal()" uses loc ... without checking for nullptr.  Seriously, run in gdb, when the segfault occurs, climb the stack "up", then inspect things ... this null ptr was easy to find.  small kudos - this code does compile.